# Merging json files

Tags: python, json, error-handling

I'm trying to merge some json files that are located in my Google colab directory (files are 0.json, 1.json, ...27.json). I'm using the below code but it gives me error. Can anyone help me through this please?

```
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        result.append(json.load(infile))

with open("merged_file.json", "wb") as outfile:
     json.dump(result, outfile)
```

the error is: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
[image: full error]

Comment: Please show the full error traceback.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I just edited the post. Please see the full error.

Comment: I seems to me like there is an issue with one of the .json files in the directory. You could do a try: except JSONDecodeError around the result.append line and print the file name on failure and look at that file to see if you see anything wrong with the JSON data in that file.

Comment: Also, show the JSON file you're trying to load. Use a decent text editor and check which file encoding it is in, and show that as well.

Comment: @Nickleman@Tomalak Thanks for your reply. You were right there was an issue with one the files. I Just fixed the issue but now when I'm trying to merge the files, it shows new error which is:TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: You are opening the file in binary mode ("wb"). Either open it as text ("w") or add some lines to encode to a string and then write the string out to the file but encode the unicode string to bytes first with .encode().

Comment: @Nickleman That worked. Thanks a lot.